# Visual Basic Error code 1004 - Application- or Objectdefined error

Tags: excel, vba

When trying to copy rows from one sheet called Data to a new sheet specified by user input I get error 1004 - Application- or objectdefined error.

It creates the sheet that I want with the name that I want but it doesn't copy over any rows.

```
Sub cond_copy()
Dim ArtikelNummer As Variant
ArtikelNummer = InputBox("Skriv in artikelnummer", "Artikelsortering"
'skapa sheet enligt artikenummer
Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=xlWorksheet)
NewSheet.Name = ArtikelNummer
 'assuming the data is in sheet1
Sheets(ArtikelNummer).Select
RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To RowCount
     'assuming the true statment is in column B
     'Range(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), Range("AG" & ActiveCell.Row).End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range("B" & i).Select
    check_value = ActiveCell
    If check_value = ArtikelNummer Or check_value = ArtikelNummer Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
         'assuming the data is in sheet2
        Sheets(ArtikelNummer).Select
        RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("B" & RowCount + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Data").Select
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Won't `RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` always equal 1 as you're counting the number of rows in the sheet you've just created?

Comment: You're checking the same value twice here: `If check_value = ArtikelNummer Or check_value = ArtikelNummer Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the code you're after:

```
Sub cond_copy()
    Dim ArtikelNummer As Variant
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    Dim check_value As Range
    ArtikelNummer = InputBox("Skriv in artikelnummer", "Artikelsortering")
    Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=xlWorksheet)
    NewSheet.Name = ArtikelNummer

    x = 1 'This is the next empty row on NewSheet.
    With Worksheets("Data")
        RowCount = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To RowCount
            If .Cells(i, 2) = ArtikelNummer Then
                .Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _
                    NewSheet.Cells(x, 1)
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

It asks for a sheet name, creates that sheet and then looks at each row on the 'Data' sheet in column B for the sheet name and copies that row to the new sheet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!

I see the differences but i still get error code 1004.
Do you have any idea on what triggers the error?

Comment: Now it doesn't trigger any error but it doesn't copy anything either, only creates the worksheet with correct name

Comment: When it did cause an error, which line did it occur on?  Does column B on the `Data` sheet have any data in it and are any of the values in column B the same as the new sheet name?

Comment: Well I don't get any error code anymore, however the new sheet is empty, as if there should be some error on the copy/paste part.

Comment: I've added an example picture - if column B in `Data` holds the value ABC in column B and you create a sheet called 'ABC' it copies those rows over.

Comment: That is exactly how I want it!
I am deeply thankful for all your help, but somehow it doesn't seem to work for me, do i need to import the visual basic script into the excel file or can it be some other error?

Comment: Are you able to upload the excel-file with the vb-script so I can check if i can copy over the data to your file?

Comment: Okey! It's working now!
The little problem was fixed by changing

Comment: If .Cells(i, 2) = ArtikelNummer Then   to If .Cells(i, 2) = Val(ArtikelNummer) Then

Comment: Ah, ok - the sheet name is a number rather than text (I should've clicked on AritkelNummer for the translation). :)

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! You are  a true champion

Comment: A quick question, if I want to select only columns B, C and E I tried using
.Cells(i, 2).Columns(B, C, E).Copy Destination:= _
Instead of
.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _

Should I specify a range instead?

Comment: Solved by using
.Cells(i, 2).Columns("A:B").Copy Destination:= _
                    NewSheet.Cells(x, 1)
                .Cells(i, 2).Columns("D:D").Copy Destination:= _
                    NewSheet.Cells(x, 3)

If anyone was interested

Comment: To test what range you're looking at:  Step through your code (F8) to the copy line, then in the `Immediate` window type `?.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Address` - this will give the address, in this case it was `$1:$1`.  Notice with your solution that `.Cells(i, 2).Columns("A:B").Address` shows `$B$1:$C$1` rather than `$A$1:$B$1` (as you asked for in the Columns statement) - this is because you're referencing column 2 and everything is moved across by a column (so A:B now returns B:C).

Comment: To select non-continuous ranges you could use `union(.cells(i,2),.cells(i,3),.cells(i,5)).Copy.....`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I've tried to fix it and the code is now:

`Sub cond_copy()
Dim ArtikelNummer As Variant
ArtikelNummer = InputBox("Skriv in artikelnummer", "Artikelsortering")
'skapa sheet enligt artikenummer
Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=xlWorksheet)
NewSheet.Name = ArtikelNummer
     'assuming the data is in sheet1
    Sheets(Data).Select
    RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To RowCount
         'assuming the true statment is in column B
        Range(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), Range("AG" & ActiveCell.Row).End(xlToLeft)).Select
        'Range("B" & i).Select
        check_value = ActiveCell
        If check_value = ArtikelNummer Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
             'assuming the data is in sheet2
            Sheets(ArtikelNummer).Select
            RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("B" & RowCount + 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Data").Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub`